# How to target asp.net MVC 1 when version 2 is installed on build machine

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dll, assemblies

I have a site that was built using asp.net MVC version 1.
I recently upgraded to visual studio 2010 which includes version 2.
Upon opening the site now, I see that it believes the runtimes for MVC for this project are at version 2 so when I publish to my server, it fails as it cannot find version 2. 
Installing MVC 2.00 is not an option on the server at the moment.
As well as this, the site was using the 'copy local' so the MVC DLL's were in the bin folder on the server (bin deployment).

Is there any way I revert this solution back to using the old version so that I can deploy it on the server without it breaking things?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open the project in Visual Studio, remove the reference of `System.Web.Mvc, v2.0` and add a reference to `System.Web.Mvc, v1.0`. Make sure in web.config you don't have a binding redirect to v2.0 and if you do, remove it. You should be good to deploy and run against MVC 1.0.